# Getting Error while Cloning the git Repository

Tags: git, github

```
C:\Users\nikhil.wagh>git clone git://github.com/nikhilrwagh/NikhilUIkit.git
Cloning into 'NikhilUIkit'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.120]: errno=No error
```

Please give me some inputs so that I can work on it.

Comment: Not clear, please elaborate your question. Also, tries to put error in SO itself.

Comment: Try my answer below if it works

Comment: I think internet connection problem, let try this latter.

Comment: The command works for me (on Linux). I'd bet an internet connection issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning using `https:`

`git clone https://github.com/nikhilrwagh/NikhilUIkit.git`

or

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```